# Find the sum of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to find the sum of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}$.

We can see that
$$\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n)!} - \frac{(2n+2)^2}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{(2n+1)^3 - (2n+2)^2}{(2n + 1)!} = \frac{8n^3+8n^2-2n-3}{(2n + 1)!} < \frac{8n^3+8n^2-2n-3}{16n^5} < \frac{16n^3}{16n^5} = \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Notice that the inequalities hold for large enough $n$.
Than the sum converges because the sum of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges and is the upper bound for our sum. However, I can not calculate what the sum converges to. If you have any ideas, please share.

Comment: Hint: Take a well known power series and differentiate it term by term.

Comment: **Hint **: write it as $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}\,x^n$, expand the square and think about a well known function

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)+3n+1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+3\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}$$

Therfore:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-2)!}+3\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}-3\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=-e^{-1}-1$$

Comment: The idea is right, but you should check your calculations.

Comment: $(-1)!$ is undefined.

Comment: Yes , (-1)! Is undifinded But $\frac{-1}{(-1)!} = 0$

Comment: @Mostafa $\frac{-1}{(-1)!} = 0$ does not make sense as it leads to $(-1)! = \frac{-1}{0}$

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Why do you think it is not true, what is wrong?

Comment: @Mostafa : the problem is not that why he thinks it is not true, why do you think it is true? what is the justification?

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}{n!}$

When solving such a problem, in my opinion, one should consider the expansion,
$$e^{x}=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+.....$$
In this question, we will mostly use the conditions $x=1$ and $x=-1$
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
and
$$e^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{1}{n!}$$
Now, coming back to the question,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}{n!}$$
The above question can be simplified thus,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{\left(n^{2}+2n+1\right)}{n!}$$
Further,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{\left(n\left(n-1\right)+3n+1\right)}{n!}$$
Now, the pattern is quite clear.

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{1}{\left(n-2\right)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{3}{\left(n-1\right)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{1}{n!}$ *

Notice the second term here. We can rewrite this as follows.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{1}{\left(n-2\right)!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}\ \frac{3}{\left(n-1\right)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\ \frac{1}{n!}$$
$$=e^{-1}-3e^{-1}+(e^{-1}-1)$$
$$=-e^{-1}-1$$

Now a question may arise that in the starred (*) equation, why was the first term started from $n=2$. The answer is due to the fact that, at $n=1$,
$$\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{n!}=\frac{0}{0!}=\frac{0}{1}=0$$
As you can see, cancelling the term $(n-1)$ cannot be cancelled at $n=1$ as it becomes zero.
(This clarifies what the previous author @Mostafa wants to say in the comment section, I typed this answer because I cannot comment yet.)

I hope that the answer is clear and sufficient.